# power of a block triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

I have a matrix in the form :

$$M =
\begin{pmatrix}
A & 0 & 0 \\\
B & A & 0 \\\
C & D & A 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $A,B,C,D$ are diagonalizable square matrices and I want to determine

$$M^{\infty}:=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} M^n$$

as a function of $A,B,C,D$.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I guess you are dealing with matrices with real or complex entries. First, we need a condition on the eigenvalues of $A$ in order to ensure $\lim_{p\to\infty}A^p$ exists in $\mathcal M_n(\Bbb C)$, as $A^p$ will be in the top-left corner of $M^p$. 

Comment: Thank you for your answer !

The matrices have real entries.
I know that $A$ has $1$ as eigenvalue and the others eigenvalues have a module strictly less than 1.

Comment: You could include this in the OP. Do we have additional information, for example about the other matrices?


Answer (score 1):

In general the limit will not exist.  For example, the $(2,1)$ block of $M^n$ is $B_n = \sum_{j=1}^n A^{j-1} B A^{n-j}$. By taking a suitable basis, we may assume $A$ is diagonal.
Under the assumption Christophe gave in a comment, that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ and the other eigenvalues have absolute value $<1$, we can write $A = \pmatrix{I & 0\cr 0 & E\cr}$
where $E^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.  If $B$ has the corresponding block structure
$\pmatrix{\alpha & \beta \cr \gamma & \delta\cr}$, then a necessary and sufficient condition
for $B_n$ to have a limit as $n \to \infty$ is $\alpha = 0$.  The limit of $B_n$ is then
$\pmatrix{0 & \beta (I - E)^{-1}\cr (I-E)^{-1} \gamma & 0\cr}$.  Similarly for the $(3,2)$ block with $B$ replaced by $D$.  The requirements for the $(3,3)$ block to have a limit seem to be more complicated.